# Поднатужимся, глагол

Tags: грамматика

Возможно ли использование слова "поднатужимся" в официальном обращении?

Answer (score 2):

Не для официальной почты или документооборота это слово.

ПОДНАТУ́ЖИТЬСЯ, -ужусь, -ужишься; совер. (***разг.***). Постараться, приложить усилия. Поднатужился и сдвинул камень. К экзамену придётся поднатужиться.

В печати — полемике, прозе — примеров множество.

> Всегда предполагалось такое светлое будущее: сегодня поднатужимся ― а
>   завтра или послезавтра обязательно будет каждому по потребностям.
>   [Самоограничение поневоле // «Знание - сила», 2006]